# Чтобы Вам было комфортнее работать с нами (,)

Tags: пунктуация

Чтобы Вам было комфортнее работать с нами (,) за ООО "Ромашка" закреплен персональный менеджер.
Уточните, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после "с нами"?
Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, запятая нужна, так как заканчивается придаточное предложение и начинается главное

Answer (score 0):

Разборка с запятой (хотя она безусловно **нужна**) — не главная проблема этого предложения: вторая его часть логически отклеилась от той, которая поставлена впереди, хотя, по сути она говорит о положительности факта «закрепления». Заменив (если послание не личное) неуместное ***Вам*** на безличное, можно получить примерно такое: «В ООО "Ромашка" продуктивное и комфортное сотрудничество вам обеспечит наш персональный менеджер».